# setting up pythreejs in JupyterLab

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-lab, pythreejs

I'm setting up pythreejs on jupyter lab.
Jupyter lab is setup using conda but there are issues with the pythreejs installation running on windows 7.

```
>>> conda --version 
4.6.14
>>> jupyter lab --version
0.32.1
>>> conda list pythreejs
pythreejs, version=2.0.2, build=py36_1001
```

When I open jupyter lab I get a the following error as pop out:

> *Build Recommended JupyterLab build is suggested jupyter-threejs needs to be included in build jupyterlab-datawidgets needs to be included in
>   build*

i click build and get:

> *Build Failed  please run 'jupyter lab build' on the server ...*

I run 'jupyter lab build' on the cmd line as admin (conda is in Program Files), node starts working away, until it freezes on the following:

```
_? jupyter-threejs@file:../extensions/jupyter-threejs-2.0.3.tgz_
```

Any suggestions?